# iOS:Add a frame based subview to a constraint based superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a constraint based super view which looks like

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500; 
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: superView
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem: nil
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier: 0.0
                              constant: _expandedHeight];
[superView addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

it's size and origin are not determined(Actually, it's the system input view in custom keyboard extension).

Is there any possibility can I add a frame based subview such as

```
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
```

to that constraint based super view?

I tried to directly add subView to the superView but got a unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints exception. Then I add

```
subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

but it still doesn't work.